# - CA SSL config issues with RESTCOMM

Tags: restcomm

First to explain our application, its as follows...
1)We have one UBUNTU server where we are running Apache Tomcat and also RESTCOMM.
2) We have two application war files.  One is the main application and another is a customized OLYMPUS Application to facilitate WebRTC calls.  Now our Main application has a menu option which when clicked will load customized OLYMPUS Application into the browser and facilitates the WEBRTC for users.
3) We have tested this properly by using Self Signed Certficate and all is working well.  But now we want to use CA apporved SSL Cert.
4) for this we have bout SSL CERT from GODADDY and for this the CSR was generated for Apache and then by using that CSR we downloaded the SSL CERT for Apache and configured by following the same process of how we configured Self Signed Cert.
5) Our main application is working well with the newly installed CA SSL Certificate.  But when we try to load the customized OLYMPUS application we are getting the following error ...**Web socket connection to ‘wss://>:/’ failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canelled.**

We are able to get all working with self signed cert, but we are stuck with this problem when we use CA Approved SSL Cert from GO DADDY.
Request your suggestions pls.

Thanks in advance
Ias M

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Restcomm to use SSL Cert as well since the Websokets secure connection goes directly to Restcomm. Which method are you using for runnning Restcomm, using the zip file or the docker image ? Also which version of Restcomm are you running ?

Comment: We are using ZIP bundle of Restcomm and we are using latest version. Initially when we are able to get it working using Self Signed CERT we followed the below two steps…
a) followed the link http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-enable-https-secure-connector-on-jboss-as-7-or-eap-6/.  Somehow we could not get it working by just following the steps in the above link.
b) Also we did SSL config in standalone.xml too by following https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/SSL+setup+guide
But this time when we followed the above two steps to configure the SSL cert from Godaddy, we are facing that error.

Comment: To add further info,The SSL Cert from GODADDy has two certs ( one chain and root one) and we used below commands to import them into KEYSTORE file which has been configured in RESTCOMM.

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file /home/RESTCOMM/Mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.4.0.746/standalone/configuration/d05d9ddbadef167a.crt -keystore p2c.keystore
 keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file /home/RESTCOMM/Mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.4.0.746/standalone/configuration/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -keystore p2c.keystore
Are we missing any more steps, pls. suggest.

Comment: There is an additional step for the SIP Over WebSockets. You need to configure the SIP Stack as well. see mode details on how we do it in the Docker image script at https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/blob/master/scripts/restcomm_sslconf.sh.

Comment: We updated the documentation at http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-enable-https-secure-connector-on-jboss-as-7-or-eap-6/ with the steps for configuring the SIP Stack. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the additional step info and yes it makes perfect sense.  We have tried that step and infact double check all the configuration once again, but we are getting the error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.  Our GODADY SSL cert was based on CSR created for Apache behind which our main application runs on TOMCAT. Similarly our customized OLYMPUS app is also deployed as WAR file on same TOMCAT.  But when ROOM.HTML file of customized OLYMPUS loads it internally runs ROOM.JS which makes WSS:<IP:5083 .  But there we are getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: Btw i want to mention that RESTCOMM was installed on the same server too and first we configured the same SSL ( created based on CSR of Apache) on RESTCOMM as per the steps mentioned in the link shared, then it didn't work. But then we thought may be the SSL was created based on CSR of Apache and it is incompatible. So we bought another SSL especially to configure on RESTCOMM and still no luck. We are still trying our other alternates, but in case if any more suggestions is truly appreciated.

Comment: Yes finally we got it fixed by following the above suggestion.  Especially we have done the additional step to configure SSI for SIP over web sockets by following the above shared article.  After that there are couple of minor issues on our env which we have taken care off, then finally we are able to get WebRTC working by configuring the CA approved SSL certs.

Comment: Great. Thanks for reporting back. Feel free to upvote the answer for other users in the future. Thanks!